# OS 10 - How to keep my account superuser?

Tags: macos, sudo

I'm not using root on my macbook, so almost every time I will get some permission error which reminds me of adding 'sudo'. But it's so awkward. Is there any way to get around this issue? Can I make my account superuser, not root but at least I don't have to sudo every time.

Comment: What do you think the difference is between superuser and root?

Comment: **Please please please** keep in mind the dangers of being root all the time. Being a regular user with administrative privileges should be sufficient for most purposes. I like to think of `sudo` as just a little reminder - "Do I really want to be running this command?" All it takes is one mis-placed character (`rm -rf / tmp/tmpdir) to really screw stuff up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: 'sudo su -'
Step 2: do things as root
Step 3: ctrl+d

As ernie said; there would be no difference if you were root or not if you gave your user all the permissions root would have had anyway. But if you are doing more than 1 sudo'ing task in a row, just use sudo su.

Answer (score 0):

I'll point out my workaround for this is usually to start a terminal, change the background color on it to something different, and then `sudo bash` and leave it up.

So, if I want to do anything root related, I pull up my terminal with the bright green background, everything else I do in other terminals.